# problema con un formulario incrementable

Tags: javascript, html

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente problema tengo un formulario incrementable dentro de una tabla html, todo funciona perfecto,el problemas es el siguiente dentro formulario incrementable tengo una lista desplegable, cuando escojo la opción de otro usuario me habilita un input esto funciona, cuando le doy mas para agregar otra fila y quiero habilitar el input de esa fila siempre me habilita la primera fila y no la segunda y son con todo los campos[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] que valla aumentando,

Este seria mi formulario

```
     <input type="hidden" name="id_r" value="<?php echo  $row['id_r'] ?>">  

     <input type="checkbox" onclick="document.getElementById('Informativa').style. display = (this.checked) ? 'block' : 'none' " name="tipo_m" value="informativa" >
      <strong>Informativa</strong>


     <input type="checkbox" onclick="document.getElementById('Acuerdo').style. display = (this.checked) ? 'block' : 'none' " name="tipo_m" value="acuerdos" >
     <strong>Acuerdo</strong>

      <div id="Informativa" style="display: none">

      <table class="table bg-info"  id="tabla">


       <tr class="fila-fija">
       <input type="hidden" name="titulo" value="<?php echo $row['titulo'] ?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="seguidor[]" value="Informativa">

        <td><label>Descripción</label>
        <textarea required name="descripcion[]"  class="form-control" placeholder="Descripcion de la Actividad"/></textarea></td>

       <td><label>Usuario</label>
       <select  class="form-control" name="usuario[]" onchange="if(this.value=='padicional') {document.getElementById('padicional').disabled = false} else {document.getElementById('usuario').disabled = true} ">
        <option></option>
        <option value="padicional">Otro Usuario</option>

        <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM usuario";
        $registros=mysql_query($query,$conexion) or die("Problemas en el select:".mysql_error());
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($registros)){
              $usuario=$row['usuario'];


        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $usuario;?>"><?php echo $usuario;?></option>

        <?php }?>

        </select>

        </td>

        <td><label>Participante adicional</label><input type="text" id="padicional" name="padicional" class="form-control" disabled></td>


        <td class="col-md-1"><label>Fecha de Ejecución</label>
        <input type="date" name="fecha_inicio[]"  value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d') ?>"  class="form-control"/></td>

        <td class="col-md-1"><label>Fecha de Seguimiento</label>
        <input type="date"  name="fecha_final[]" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d') ?>" class="form-control"/></td>



        <td class="eliminar"><label>Quitar</label><p></p><input class="btn btn-danger" type="button"   value="Menos -"/></td>

      </tr>



    </table>
    <div class="btn-der">
      <input type="submit" value="Registrar Actividad" class="btn btn-info"/>
      <button id="adicional" name="adicional" type="button" class="btn btn-warning"> Más + </button>

    </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Este es el javascript que incrementa

```
    $(function(){

    // Clona la fila oculta que tiene los campos base, y la agrega al final de la tabla
    $("#adicional").on('click', function(){
      $("#tabla tbody tr:eq(0)").clone().removeClass('fila-fija').appendTo("#tabla");




    });




    // Evento que selecciona la fila y la elimina 
    $(document).on("click",".eliminar",function(){
      var parent = $(this).parents().get(0);
      $(parent).remove();
    });





 });
</script>
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta y añade el código por favor pare que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: participante adicional, en ambos input(el de la fila 1 y 2) tiene el mismo Id, "probablemente", por lo cual jquery siempre va a tomar el que encuentre primero en el dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno varias cosas:

1. Te recomiendo cambiar los `id` de todos los elementos por clases, ¿Por qué? por que como estás generando filas nuevas van a quedar con `id` repetidos y las buenas prácticas de `html` dictan que un `id` es un identificador único he irrepetible en el sitio.
2. Si estás usando `jQuery` para realizar algunas funciones utilízalo también para el evento `change` del `select` en cuestión.
3. Te dejo un código de como te debería de funcionar correctamente lo que quieres lograr:

   ```
   <select  class="form-control" name="usuario[]" class="selectUsuario">

   $(".selectUsuario").change(function(){
   if($(this).val() == 'padicional'){
       $(this).parent().parent().find('#padicional').attr('disabled','disabled');
   }else {
       $(this).parent().parent().find('#padicional').removeAttr('disabled');
   }
   })
   ```

Espero que te sirva, saludos !

Comment: Muchas Gracias Camilo

Comment: Si la respuesta solucionó tu problema te invito a marcarla como aceptada para que los futuros desarrolladores que tengan un problema similar sepan que es la solución correcta, además te invito a que te hagas el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y te des una leída de [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) saludos !